# Real analysis problem from sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Suppose we have ${x_{n}}$ as a increasing sequence and another sequence ${y_{n}}$ which is defined as $y_{n}=\frac {x_{n}}{1+|x_{n}|}$ then prove that the sequence $y_{n}$ is increasing and comment upon the fact whether it is cauchy or not !

My problem basically is that in the first part by using the definition of an increasing sequence I am not able to make sense of how to prove that $ x_{n+1} |x_{n}| - x_{n} |x_{n+1}|  > 0$ and for the next part i don't have any idea of how to approach the problem ! Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $0\leq x \leq y$ . Then $x+x|y|\leq  y+y|x|$. If $x \leq y \leq 0$ then $x+x|y|=x-xy\leq  y-yx=y+y|x|$. If $x \leq 0 \leq y$ then $x+x|y|=x+xy \leq y-xy= y+y|x|$ because $xy \leq 0$ in this case. This proves that $\frac x {1+|x|} \leq \frac y {1+|y|}$ whenever $x \leq y$. Hence $(y_n)$ is increasing.

The second sequence is increasing and bounded, hence convergent (hence Cauchy). Note that $|y_n| \leq 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Sir but what about the second part of the problem ? I am getting no clues for it !

Comment: $(y_n)$ is Cauchy because it is increasing and bounded.

Comment: Okay I got thanks